# Springboot - NoSuchMethodException: - org.springframework.boot.devtools.logger.DevToolsLogFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to run a test in one of the demo project but I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.devtools.logger.DevToolsLogFactory`. It runs fine within eclipse but doesn't work in Jenkins. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Test class: `BanksMvcControllerTest.java`

```
package com.WebDemo.Controller;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.webDemo.WebApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = WebApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class BanksMvcControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

I get the error `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.devtools.logger.DevToolsLogFactory$Listener.<init>()`

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.032 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.WebDemo.Controller.BanksMvcControllerTest
08:00:47.055 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.WebDemo.Controller.BanksMvcControllerTest]
08:00:47.056 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.WebDemo.Controller.BanksMvcControllerTest]
08:00:47.056 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.WebDemo.Controller.BanksMvcControllerTest]
08:00:47.057 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.WebDemo.Controller.BanksMvcControllerTest]
08:00:47.058 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.WebDemo.Controller.BanksMvcControllerTest]
08:00:47.058 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.WebDemo.Controller.BanksMvcControllerTest]
08:00:47.092 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@35fc6dc4] to prepare test instance [com.WebDemo.Controller.BanksMvcControllerTest@16e7dcfd]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140) ~[surefire-api-2.4.2.jar:2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127) ~[surefire-api-2.4.2.jar:2.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177) ~[surefire-api-2.4.2.jar:2.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338) ~[surefire-booter-2.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997) ~[surefire-booter-2.4.2.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.devtools.logger.DevToolsLogFactory.Listener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:381) ~[spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:358) ~[spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:231) ~[spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:206) ~[spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.getSpringApplication(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:124) ~[spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.devtools.logger.DevToolsLogFactory$Listener.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:376) ~[spring-boot-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>demo-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <groupId>demo-spring-boot</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>baseapp/pom.xml</relativePath>    
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <artifactId>demo-web</artifactId>
    <groupId>demo-web</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <artifactId>demo-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>demo-api</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-jndi</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version> 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>  
    </build>              
</project>
```

Comment: Fix your dependencies, those errors are generally from mixing jars from different versions of a framework. YOu are using devtools from Spring BOot 2.5.5 where I suspect your spring boot version is lower. Just remove `<version>` from the dependency. Also `spring-mvc` is already part of `spring-boot-starter-web` and `junit` is part of `spring-boot-starter-test` so you should remove those. Also the `javaee-api` jar should be `provided` scope (if you ask me).

Comment: When I remove it, jenkins reports we need to specify version `[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar is missing. @ line 34, column 21
`

Comment: Which means you aren't using the Spring Boot parent. If you include it make sure it aligns with the other `spring-boot-starter-*` dependency version, and I doubt it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it.

I had to remove the following dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And include `org.apache.logging` instead.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
  </dependency>
```